# Jersey test address already in use when running multiple methods

Tags: java, jersey

I am trying to test my rest interface with a class that inherits from JerseyTest. While the first test method succeeds without any problem, the following tests fail with an bind exception Address already in use. Do I need to release some kind of resource in between the tests to get this running?

```
class MyClass extends JerseyTest () {
    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(MyClass.class);
    }
    @Test
    testFirstThing() {
        // test some request  
    }
    @Test
    testFirstThing() {
        // test another request  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had the same issue today, some of the tests passed, but some failed with BindException

There is a solution in Jersey Test documentation:
https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html#parallel

> For a purpose of running multiple test containers in parallel you need
>   to set the TestProperties.CONTAINER_PORT to 0 value. This will tell
>   Jersey Test Framework (and the underlying test container) to use the
>   first available port.

```
@Override
protected Application configure() {
    forceSet(TestProperties.CONTAINER_PORT, "0");
    return new ResourceConfig(MyClass.class);
}
```

Comment: Excellent it works perfectly!! Thank you very much ;)

Comment: Works beautifully! +1

Comment: The link to the docs just directs to the homepage. I think it needs changing to: https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/test-framework.html#parallel